# Why won't my air conditioner work after a power outtage?

Tags: air-conditioning

The air conditioner does not work at all. I'm wondering if it's a power problem? The thermostat isn't even on and doesn't show a temperature. Before it stopped working the power had gone out due to storms, could that have contributed to why it is not working now?

Comment: It may seem that some circuit inside the devise is destroyed due to this electrical discharge. It may contribute to the state it is now. My small advise is to consider exchange (if warranty is valid) or to let some specialist look into it (to check if it's really that broken).

Comment: Are there any breakers/fuses tripped in your electrical panel? Do you own; or can you procure, a volt meter or multimeter? Do you have access to the furnace/air handler? Are you handy enough to poke around in HVAC equipment?

Comment: looks like your thermostat is a goner. what sort of thermostat is it? if it's the newer digital style, try putting in a new set of batteries. or, these things are fairly cheap, so replace it and see if the display's still out.

Comment: What kind of air conditioner is it? Is this sitting outside on a concrete pad or hanging out of a window.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a breaker integral to the AC that has tripped= a little red button you have to press to reset it.